# Linear Regression Theta Parameters Go to Infinity

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I implemented a linear regression from scratch for educational purposes. Although it works well with small-scaled datasets, when I created a polynomial dataset, my model's theta values go to infinity. Here is the theta parameters:

while number of iterations is 309:

```
array([[1.56866981e+298],
       [9.27890019e+298],
       [3.10644422e+299],
       [5.55196729e+299],
       [1.78766584e+300],
       [7.10668519e+300],
       [1.56866981e+298]])
```

while number of iterations is 310:

```
array([[-1.49254121e+299],
       [-8.82858890e+299],
       [-2.95568639e+300],
       [-5.28252657e+300],
       [-1.70090921e+301],
       [            -inf],
       [-1.49254121e+299]])
```

while number of iterations is 311:

```
array([[inf],
       [inf],
       [inf],
       [inf],
       [inf],
       [nan],
       [inf]])
```

Here is my linear regression class:

```
# Multivariate Linear Regression implemented by Hizir Can Bayram.

import sys
import numpy as np

from measuring_metrics import MeasurementMetrics

class MultivariateLinearRegression(MeasurementMetrics):


    # Param | reg_rate : if the model is regularized linear regression, regularization rate        
    def __init__(self, learning_rate, learning_algorithm, epoch_num, reg_rate = None):
        MeasurementMetrics.__init__(self, epoch_num)
        self._learning_rate = learning_rate
        self._learning_algoritm = learning_algorithm
        self._epoch_num = epoch_num
        self._theta = 0
        self._training_sample = 0
        self._reg_rate = reg_rate
        self._log = []

    # Trains the model and calculates the parameters of multivariate linear regression model based on the learning algorithm
    # given as parameter.
    # Param | X : independent variables of shape numpy array.
    # Param | Y : dependent variable of shape numpy array.
    def train(self, X, Y):
        if self._learning_algoritm == 'Gradient Descent':
            self._trainGradientDescent(X, Y, self._reg_rate)
        elif self._learning_algoritm == 'Normal Equation':
            self._trainNormalEquation(X, Y, self._reg_rate)
        else:
            print('No such a learning algorithm. Check the learning algorithm\'s name given as parameter. It should be either \'Gradient Descent\' or \'Normal Equation\'')
            sys.exit()



    # Trains the model with gradient descent optimization algorithm.
    # Param | X : independent variables of shape numpy array.
    # Param | Y : dependent variable of shape numpy array.   
    def _trainGradientDescent(self, X, Y, reg_rate):
        Y = Y.reshape((Y.size, 1))
        if len(X.shape) == 1:
            X = X.reshape((X.size, 1)) 
        bias = np.ones([X.shape[0], 1])
        X = np.concatenate((X, bias), 1)

        self._theta = np.zeros([X.shape[1], 1])
        self._training_sample = X.shape[0]
        loading_rate = self._epoch_num // 10

        for i in range (self._epoch_num):
            hypothesis = X.dot(self._theta)
            difference = np.subtract(hypothesis, Y) # hypothesis function - y values (for all training sample in the dataset, leading a vector of size m where m is the training sample in the dataset)
            #cost_val = (np.sum(difference) ** 2) / self._training_sample
            #self._cost_vals.append(cost_val)
            cost_func = np.transpose(X).dot(difference)
            gradient = (self._learning_rate / self._training_sample) * cost_func
            if self._reg_rate != None:
                reg_factor = (1 - (self._learning_rate * self._reg_rate) / self._training_sample)
                self._theta = np.subtract(reg_factor * self._theta, gradient)
            else:
                self._theta = np.subtract(self._theta, gradient)
            self._log.append(self._theta)
            if i % loading_rate == 0:
                print('- ', end=' ')
        print()




    # Trains the model with normal equation optimization algorithm.
    # Param | X : independent variables of shape numpy array.
    # Param | Y : dependent variable of shape numpy array. 
    def _trainNormalEquation(self, X, Y):
        print('it will be implemented')



    # Predicts the dependent variable based on the given independent variable as parameter.
    # Param | X : independent variable sample of shape python list.
    # Return | : prediction of shape a number.
    def predict(self, X):
        X = np.array(X)
        bias = np.ones([1]).reshape((1,1))
        if len(X.shape) == 1:
            X = X.reshape((X.size, 1)) 
        X = np.concatenate((X, bias), 1)

        return X.dot(self._theta)[0][0]
```

Here is my test script:

```
from multi_variate_linear_regression import MultivariateLinearRegression 

from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd  # for preprocessing the data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # for plotting the graph
import seaborn as sns 


datas = pd.read_csv('boston_housing.csv')
rm = datas['rm'].to_numpy()
rm = rm.reshape((len(rm), 1))
lstat = datas['lstat'].to_numpy()
lstat = lstat.reshape((len(lstat), 1))
linear_X = np.concatenate((rm, lstat), 1)
Y = datas['medv'].to_numpy()
Y = Y.reshape((len(Y), 1))
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(linear_X, Y, test_size=0.25, random_state=0)

mlr = MultivariateLinearRegression(0.0001, 'Gradient Descent', 5000, None)
mlr.train(X_train, Y_train)



poly_features = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
X_train_poly = poly_features.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_poly = poly_features.fit_transform(X_test) 

mlr_poly = MultivariateLinearRegression(0.0001, 'Gradient Descent', 400, None)
mlr_poly.train(X_train_poly, Y_train)
```

The dataset I used is boston housing and can be found here:
https://github.com/selva86/datasets/blob/master/BostonHousing.csv

However, when I worked with sklearn Ridge liear model, the datas did not go to infinity. That is the code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
clf = Ridge(alpha=0.0001, max_iter=50000, normalize=False)
clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

It works well without polynomial features.
How to avoid this infinite, Nan issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Linear regression becomes complicated really fast when there are a lot of features. Polynomial regression will add all combinations of features thus makes it even more complicated.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Mr. However, when I work with sklearn Ridge model with the same parameters, that did not go to infinity:

I updated the question with that line of codes. Please refer to it.

Where is my problem, how can I avoid that without normalizing... I'm stuck in this for more than a week...

Answer (score 0):

If the ridge model works and the plain linear model does not, It's likely due to your x is overfitted on y thus makes theta infinitely small. What Ridge Model does is that it restricts the model to become absurd. I am not great on the math itself so that is my surmise given the differences between Ridge and Plain linear model. So, in another word, the way to stop theta reaches infinite is to Ridge model. Hope this helps.